# how to use jquery to fade out anything but the selected element?

Tags: jquery, css, fade

i have a few li elements created like this:

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($test as $value){
echo '<li class="li_class">.$value['name'].</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

this will give me:

```
<li class="li_class">name1</li>
<li class="li_class">name2</li>
<li class="li_class">name3</li>
...
```

what i want to do is when i hover over a li element all other li elements to fade out about 50%.

i could have 2 classes and use jquery to change them:

```
.li_class{
background: #ccc;
} 

.fade{
opacity: .5;
}
```

bur i don't know how to tell jquery to add the `.fade` class to all other li but not the one i am hovering with the mouse.

any ideas? is there another way of doing this?

---

**edit:**

thanks to you all i came up with this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {   
    $('.li_class').hoverIntent(function(){
         $(this).removeClass('fade').siblings().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, 500);
    },function(){
         $(this).siblings().andSelf().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 100);
    });
});
```

using the  `hoverIntent` plugin.

Comment: See my updated answer, I think it's even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
$('.li_class').hover(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('fade').siblings().addClass('fade');
},function(){
     $(this).siblings().andSelf().removeClass('fade');
})
```

Comment: @Patrioticcow. Please check mine, I think it maybe even better.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.li_class').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().addClass('fade');
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('fade');
});​
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/YwKVt/3/)

Comment: `siblings` is a method and you are using it as a property. Even if you fix that it will not work as OP expect.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli. First thanks for the typo. Enlight me please, why?

Comment: @Patrioticcow. There was a typo, check again... =)

Comment: You are adding the fade class on mouse over to siblings but not removing from the element you hovered. And same while removing the calss.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli. I think you're wrong. I'm trying to make a JSFiddle, but I got problems with that site. Please check it out.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli. As I said, It does work... See the JSFiddle. Upvote please... **=)**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do. use hover():

```
$('li.li_class').hover(function(){
$('li.li_class').not(this).animate('slow',{opacity: 0.5});
}, 
function(){
$('li.li_class').animate('slow',{opacity: 1});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".li_class").hover(function(){
  $(".li_class").not(this).fadeOut('slow', .5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you wanna make it execute slightly faster use `on()` instead:

```
$(".li_class").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).siblings().addClass("fade");
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("fade");
});
```